leafonyの開発環境について教えてください
「Basic Kit 2：超小型・低消費電力システム向きの開発キット」の購入を考えています。
開発内容はパソコンにBLEドングルを挿してそこからデータを取得するソフトを作成したいと考えています。
開発環境は、Windows10、VisualStudio2017、VisualC#、Microsoft.Windows.SDK.Contractsです。
ファームウェアやデータをどう送信しているかの情報はまだ得られていませんが、上記のようなソフト作成は可能でしょうか？
他社のBLE機器でIDとデバイス名から接続するまでの経験はあります。
よろしくお願いいたします。

何ができるのかは 公式のスタートガイド をまず熟読する必要があると思います。

用意するものにWindowsのパソコンの記載がありました。たいへんありがとうございました。
